# Group by for XML Path ibn SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql, for-xml-path

I am trying to concatenate some values from a column into a single field.

So far I have the below code.

```
SELECT DISTINCT [customer id]
      ,[customer name]
      ,STUFF( (SELECT ',' + [description] 
                             FROM [Invoicing].[dbo].[CurrentBillMaster] 
                             ORDER BY [description]
                             FOR XML PATH('')),
                            1, 1, '')
      ,[id]
      ,[Section]
      ,[customerpo]
  FROM [Invoicing].[dbo].[CurrentBillMaster]
  GROUP BY [customer id], [customer name], [description],[qty],
           [identifier],[FromDate],[ToDate],[id],[Section],[customerpo]
```

The code largely works, however I want the concatenated description, just to show descriptions for that unique [customer id]

Any help greatly appreciated

Comment: add sample data and expected output to get better answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to correlate subquery:

```
SELECT  [customer id]
      ,[customer name]
      ,STUFF( (SELECT ',' + [description] 
                             FROM [Invoicing].[dbo].[CurrentBillMaster] t
                             WHERE  t.Customer_id = c.customer_id  -- here
                             ORDER BY [description]
                             FOR XML PATH('')),
                            1, 1, '')
      ,[id]
      ,[Section]
      ,[customerpo]
  FROM [Invoicing].[dbo].[CurrentBillMaster] c
  GROUP BY [customer id], [customer name], [description],[qty],
           [identifier],[FromDate],[ToDate],[id],[Section],[customerpo]
```